# How to make grub actually start Windows 8 in a classic BIOS PC

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader, boot-repair

Every time I install an Ubuntu operating system flavor it correctly recognizes the Windows 8 partition, however at boot (it's legacy BIOS), after I choose Windows 8 from the GRUB menu, the screen goes dark and the Windows 8 bootloader is not loaded (it never loads Windows 8). Boot-Repair doesn't repair that. If I use `bootrec /fixmbr` (via a Windows 8 recovery USB) Windows 8 boots again, but GRUB is gone, so I have to start the PC via a Boot-Repair USB, which fixes my Ubuntu flavors, but once again Windows 8 doesn't work. And so on in an infinite loop.

On a legacy BIOS laptop (no UEFI, no Secure Boot) I have installed Windows 8.1 in the first primary partition (sda1). The partition has the boot flag.  I have disabled Windows 8's Fast Startup. Windows Update is set to manual; it doesn't re-enable Fast Startup.

On some logical partitions I have installed a few Ubuntu flavors (MATE, Kubuntu, Xubuntu. I tried vanilla Ubuntu 16.04 and 20.10.

GRUB is installed in the MBR of SDA (it also was purged and reinstalled by Boot Repair).

I have tried fixing the GRUB both from a Boot-Repair USB and from the program installed in MATE.

I have tried the repair several times; I always would click the details to see what default fixes will Boot-Repair apply; once there was "install GRUB in every partition", I didn't use it like that because I don't want my separate data partitions to be broken. In all other repairs Boot-Repair didn't auto-select such option.

I attached some of the reports generated by Boot-Repair. Ignore sda10 errors as that is an unformatted partition with no OS.

This is one of the first boot info reports:
[boot info](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/V8nzJ777jR/)

The first [Boot Repair Summary](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yqTkdqKg2N/)
The last after repair [Boot Repair Summary](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vTHymZy7pM/)

```
boot-repair-4ppa125                                              [20210307_0300]

============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================


Error code 12
mount -r /dev/sda10 /mnt/boot-sav/sda10

mount -r /dev/sda10 : Error code 12
Error code 12
mount -r /dev/sda10 /mnt/boot-sav/sda10

mount -r /dev/sda10 : Error code 12
Error code 12
mount -r /dev/sda10 /mnt/boot-sav/sda10

mount -r /dev/sda10 : Error code 12

NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda10': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda10' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda10': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda10' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda10': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda10' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda10': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda10' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub2 of
sda5 into the MBR of sda,
using the following options:       set-windows-as-default
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s



Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda5/etc/default/grub

========================= Reinstall the grub2 of sda5 ==========================

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.02-2ubuntu8.21

==> Reinstall the GRUB of sda5 into the MBR of sda

grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-66-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-66-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
Found Windows 8 on /dev/sda1
Found Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (18.04) on /dev/sda12

Set menuentry 'Windows 8 (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os  'osprober-chain-0AA6F5F7A6F5E35D' { as default entry

update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-66-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-66-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
Found Windows 8 on /dev/sda1
Found Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (18.04) on /dev/sda12

NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda10': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda10' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda10': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda10' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda5/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda12/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos5)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda8 starts 
                       at sector 2048.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda9: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda9 starts 
                       at sector 2048.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda10: _________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda11: _________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda12: _________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img


================================ 3 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS CurrentSession on sda5
OS#2:   Windows 8 on sda1
OS#3:   Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on sda12

============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-66-generic root=UUID=2e369f8f-d83e-436b-b6dc-2717c63bfddb ro quiet splash


===================================== UEFI =====================================

This installed-session is not in EFI-mode.



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda5    : is-os,    32, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
sda1    : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda6    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda7    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda8    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda9    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda11   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda12   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
sda10   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda5    : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot
sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda6    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda7    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda8    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda9    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda11   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda12   : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda10   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda5    : not-sepboot,  with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sda1    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda2    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda6    : maybesepboot, no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda7    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda8    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda9    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda11   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda12   : not-sepboot,  with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sda10   : maybesepboot, no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x10a94cd5
      Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1  *          2048   91803647   91801600  43.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda2         91803648  176549887   84746240  40.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda3        176549950 1730498559 1553948610   741G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
sda5        176549952  238813247   62263296  29.7G 83 Linux
sda6        238815296  301078591   62263296  29.7G 83 Linux
sda7        381351936  767170559  385818624   184G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda8        767172608 1154803711  387631104 184.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda9       1154805760 1730291711  575485952 274.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda10      1730293760 1730498559     204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda11       373164032  381349887    8185856   3.9G  b W95 FAT32
sda12       301080576  337934335   36853760  17.6G 83 Linux
Partition table entries are not in disk order.

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:msdos:ATA ST1000LM048-2E71:;
1:1049kB:47.0GB:47.0GB:ntfs::boot;
2:47.0GB:90.4GB:43.4GB:ntfs::;
3:90.4GB:886GB:796GB:::lba;
5:90.4GB:122GB:31.9GB:ext4::;
6:122GB:154GB:31.9GB:ext4::;
12:154GB:173GB:18.9GB:ext4::;
11:191GB:195GB:4191MB:fat32::;
7:195GB:393GB:198GB:ntfs::;
8:393GB:591GB:198GB:ntfs::;
9:591GB:886GB:295GB:ntfs::;
10:886GB:886GB:105MB:::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME    FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                 
├─sda1  ntfs     0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                     10a94cd5-01                                   
├─sda2  ntfs     4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                     10a94cd5-02                                 
├─sda3                                                10a94cd5-03                                   
├─sda5  ext4     2xxxxxxx                             10a94cd5-05                                   
├─sda6  ext4     5xxxxxxx                             10a94cd5-06                               
├─sda7  ntfs     5xxxxxxx                             10a94cd5-07                               
├─sda8  ntfs     Fxxxxxxx                             10a94cd5-08                          d     
├─sda9  ntfs     Fxxxxxxx                             10a94cd5-09                          u 
├─sda10                                               10a94cd5-0a                                   
├─sda11 vfat     Exxxxxxx                             10a94cd5-0b                          O     
└─sda12 ext4     axxxxxxx                             10a94cd5-0c                                   

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

       Avail Use% Mounted on
sda11      3G  24% /mnt/boot-sav/sda11
sda12   10.7G  33% /mnt/boot-sav/sda12
sda1    31.5G  28% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
sda2    40.3G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
sda5    17.9G  33% /
sda6    27.8G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/sda6
sda7    36.1G  80% /media/laptop/temp
sda8   107.2G  42% /mnt/boot-sav/sda8
sda9   274.3G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/sda9

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

sda11  rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
sda12  rw,relatime
sda1   rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda2   rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda5   rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro
sda6   rw,relatime
sda7   rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda8   rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda9   rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096

====================== sda5/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Windows 8 (on sda1)   0AA6F5F7A6F5E35D
Ubuntu   2e369f8f-d83e-436b-b6dc-2717c63bfddb
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-66-generic   2e369f8f-d83e-436b-b6dc-2717c63bfddb
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-42-generic   2e369f8f-d83e-436b-b6dc-2717c63bfddb
Windows 8 (on sda1)   0AA6F5F7A6F5E35D
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (18.04) (on sda12)   adeb74d4-5eef-48dd-a8eb-72bdc11859a5
Ubuntu (on sda12)   adeb74d4-5eef-48dd-a8eb-72bdc11859a5
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-29-generic (on sda12)   adeb74d4-5eef-48dd-a8eb-72bdc11859a5
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda5/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=2e369f8f-d83e-436b-b6dc-2717c63bfddb /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-ffff_5678_18080706005120-0:0 /mnt/usb-ffff_5678_18080706005120-0:0 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto,x-gvfs-show 0 0

======================= sda5/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT="menuentry 'Windows 8 (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os  'osprober-chain-0AA6F5F7A6F5E35D' {"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="visible"
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
export GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="light-gray/black"
export GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="magenta/black"
GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY="true"
==================== sda5: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
  98.701229095 = 105.979637760  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 110.512825012 = 118.662242304  boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
  87.591823578 = 94.051004416   boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic                  2
  95.404354095 = 102.439645184  boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-66-generic                  1
  95.404354095 = 102.439645184  vmlinuz                                        1
  87.591823578 = 94.051004416   vmlinuz.old                                    2
  94.864063263 = 101.859512320  boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic               3
  97.917369843 = 105.137975296  boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-66-generic               3
  97.917369843 = 105.137975296  initrd.img                                     3
  94.864063263 = 101.859512320  initrd.img.old                                 3

===================== sda5: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12808 ian  7 15:45 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11298 ian  7 15:45 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 ian  7 15:45 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1418 ian  7 15:45 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 ian  7 15:45 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 ian  7 15:45 41_custom
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 mar  7 00:34 backup

===================== sda12/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   adeb74d4-5eef-48dd-a8eb-72bdc11859a5
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-29-generic   adeb74d4-5eef-48dd-a8eb-72bdc11859a5
Windows 8 (on sda1)   0AA6F5F7A6F5E35D
Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (18.04) (on sda5)   2e369f8f-d83e-436b-b6dc-2717c63bfddb
Ubuntu (on sda5)   2e369f8f-d83e-436b-b6dc-2717c63bfddb
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-66-generic (on sda5)   2e369f8f-d83e-436b-b6dc-2717c63bfddb
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-42-generic (on sda5)   2e369f8f-d83e-436b-b6dc-2717c63bfddb
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda12/etc/fstab (filtered) ==========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda12 during installation
UUID=adeb74d4-5eef-48dd-a8eb-72bdc11859a5 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

====================== sda12/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

=================== sda12: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 143.566417694 = 154.153267200  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 150.016685486 = 161.079189504  boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
 150.014934540 = 161.077309440  boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic                 1
 150.014934540 = 161.077309440  vmlinuz                                        1
 158.491592407 = 170.179051520  boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic              2
 158.491592407 = 170.179051520  initrd.img                                     2
 158.491592407 = 170.179051520  initrd.img.old                                 2

===================== sda12: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) =====================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12693 iul 17  2018 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11298 iul 17  2018 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 iul 17  2018 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1418 iul 17  2018 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 iul 17  2018 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 iul 17  2018 41_custom


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown BootLoader on sda7

Unknown BootLoader on sda10
```

I also installed Grub Customizer to try out to move Windows 8 to the first position in the boot sequence, but it made no difference. If it's any help (because the Ubuntu pastes will expire), here is the GRUB menu entry for Windows 8:

```
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  xxxxxxxxxx
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root xxxxxxxxxx
fi
parttool ${root} hidden-
drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
chainloader +1
```

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. And Windows 8 or 10 with updates turn fast start up/hibernation flag on and then grub will not boot it. Better to have Windows on its own drive & grub booting from another drive. Or use UEFI where ESP - efi system partition is like having multiple MBRs so you can directly boot Windows from UEFI menu. But you still typically need a Windows repair/recovery flash drive & Ubuntu live installer for current version of systems you have installed to be able to make repairs.

Comment: @oldfred I already have disabled Fast Startup. Anyway thanks for the comment.

Comment: @oldfred Also, by having windows on its own drive, do you mean physical drive? It's a laptop so I can't make it. Given that Fast Startup is disabled, maybe there is a solution.

Comment: But did fast start up get turned back on with Windows update? And yes separate physical drive is best. You can live with having to switch boot loaders when ever Windows has issues and grub does not boot it, or have Ubuntu on external drive for booting. But then you always need external drive to boot Ubuntu. I found SSD in external USB3 enclosure almost as fast as internal SSD. But I do not have Windows, but want to directly boot different installs. I do have desktop with two drives, so not a issue for me. And I use UEFI, now.

Comment: @oldfred It didn't get turned back on, anyway I have Windows update set to manual, so I would disable it before shutdown. I have also put this question because the problem seems to be in the configuration that grub does, maybe it misses something. It's an old laptop with USB 2.0.

Comment: @karel No, thanks anyway; I updated the question; maybe if that answer with the custom windows cfg would be customized for my bios version...

Comment: Boot-Repair did not show the detail on the Windows 8 entry in grub.cfg. Is above entry from os-prober or Grub-customizer? I would not think you need the drivemap with one drive, that is normally for two drives.  I have seen insmod ntldr and then ntldr /bootmgr as boot lines in place of chainloader.

Comment: @oldfred It's from Grub customizer. Do you have any link or more specific details on that change? For example, should I replace just "chainloader +1" with ntldr /bootmgr and insmod part_msdos with insmod ntldr?

Comment: I had it in my notes. Found example here, but BIOS boot is now very old. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB Note that Grub Customizer replaces the grub scripts with its own "proxy" scripts. May need to use Boot-Repair's advanced mode to totally reinstall grub to restore it to its defaults, first.

Comment: @oldfred Thank you, that last one helped me (with a tweak) to answer my own question, I have created a script. [answer link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1323154/1191598)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After help from @oldfred in the [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1323029/how-to-make-grub-actually-start-windows-8-in-a-classic-bios-pc#comment2255035_1323029), I tried the custom script from that archlinux page (find in page after ntldr keyword).

I still used Grub Customizer to edit the menu entry.

The default script for Windows 8 (in that page) would create (when I chosed the Windows entry, when I was "live" in GRUB at boot!) a new menu entry with the same name, at the end of the list! If I chosed again the same Windows entry, it would create another identic menu entry at the end and so on... If I then chosed the new created menu entry at the end, it would start Windows.

However I wanted to make it to behave normal, so I tweaked it a little, then problem solved, no more 2-step menu bootup!

This is the GRUB Customizer menu entry that works (in the parameters described in my post, that is BIOS and multi-boot with Windows 8.1; for other setups there would be needed other adaptations):

```
if [ "${grub_platform}" == "pc" ]; then
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ntfs
        insmod ntldr     
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 xxxxxxxx
ntldr /bootmgr
fi
```

Where xxxxxxxx is the windows partition UUID, which can be found with command

```
lsblk --fs
```